# Navigation in Android Studio Jetpack Compose overlapping with other screen

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm new in Android Developing. Currently I'm using Jetpack Compose and for now I'm studying about Navigation but after I tried it Myself it didn't work correctly. the Main Issue was the navigation really go to the destination screen but it still overlapping with the start destination so the start destination text is overlapping with the destination screen text

can you guys help me what is wrong with my code?

This is MainScreen.kt

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val navController:NavHostController = rememberNavController()
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center)
    {
        Text(text = "Ini Halaman Utama",
            color = Color.Blue,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
    }
    SetupNavGraph(navController = navController)
    Search(navController = navController)
}
```

This is Main Activity.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import com.example.latihannavigation.ui.theme.LatihanNavigationTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            LatihanNavigationTheme {
                MainScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is NavGraph.kt

```
@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph(navController: NavHostController){
    NavHost(navController = navController,
        startDestination =Screen.Search.route){
            composable(route = Screen.Search.route) {
                MainScreen()
        }
            composable(route = Screen.Setting.route){
                Pengaturan(navController = navController)
            }
    }
}
```

this is Screen Sealed class

```
package com.example.latihannavigation

sealed class Screen(val route:String){
    object Search: Screen(route = "Screen_Home")
    object Setting: Screen(route = "Screen_Setting")
}
```

This is SearchBar.kt

```
@Composable
fun Search(navController: NavHostController){
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        ){
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Settings,
                contentDescription = "Masuk Ke Menu Settings",
                tint = Color.Black,
                modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                    navController.navigate(route = Screen.Setting.route)
                })
    }
}
```

This is Setting.kt

```
@Composable
fun Pengaturan(navController: NavHostController) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center)
    {
        Text(text = "Ini Adalah Halaman Pengaturan", color = Color.Red)
    }
    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
        contentDescription = "Kembali Ke Halaman Utama",
        tint = Color.Red,
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable {navController.navigate(route = Screen.Search.route)})
}

}
```

the two screen is Setting.kt and MainScreen.kt

I tried to use navigate in jetpack compose and I'm expecting that the two-screen connected through icon button that I make.

Comment: give proper explanation

Comment: Hello sir, I tried to use navigation through 2 screen first is mainscreen.kt and the second one is setting.kt , the code working correctly the icon can be clickable in mainscreen and in the setting screen but if you clicked the icon in the mainscreen it show and overlapping with other screen instead navigate me into whole nee screen it just overlapping previous screen

Comment: That all is the code and file that I'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made an example for you. Check it

```
package com.example.jetpackcomposeplayground

import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.Icon
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowBack
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Settings
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController


@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
    SetupNavGraph(navController = navController)

}

@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.Search.route
    ) {
        composable(route = Screen.Search.route) {
            HomeScreen {
                navController.navigate(it)
            }
        }
        composable(route = Screen.Setting.route) {
            Pengaturan(navController = navController)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navigateTo: (route: String) -> Unit) {
    Column {
        Search(navigateTo = navigateTo)
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .weight(1f), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        )
        {
            Text(
                text = "Ini Halaman Utama",
                color = Color.Blue,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
        }
    }
}

sealed class Screen(val route: String) {
    object Search : Screen(route = "Screen_Home")
    object Setting : Screen(route = "Screen_Setting")
}

@Composable
fun Search(navigateTo: (route: String) -> Unit) {
    Box(

    ) {
        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Settings,
            contentDescription = "Masuk Ke Menu Settings",
            tint = Color.Black,
            modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                navigateTo(Screen.Setting.route)
            })
    }
}

@Composable
fun Pengaturan(navController: NavHostController) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    )
    {
        Text(text = "Ini Adalah Halaman Pengaturan", color = Color.Red)
    }
    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
        contentDescription = "Kembali Ke Halaman Utama",
        tint = Color.Red,
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable { navController.navigate(route = Screen.Search.route) })
}
```